# ImageView displaying the same image after GridView item has been clicked

Tags: android, gridview

I'm having a problem which is probably much simple than I think. I have a GridView that load images from URL sent in JSON. The Url are then converted to bitmap and every image is passed to a GridView item. That all works perfectly. Then when i click on the image I send the image url to another view that displays it in fulls size, my problem is that every time I click on an item in the GridView it always loads the image in the last item of that GridView, so I'm asumming that probably when I send the image url to the next view I'm always passing the url of the last image. Does someone know what I can do to display the proper image after it has been clicked in the list view? any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
/**
 * Background AsyncTask to load profiles images by making HTTP Request
 */
class GetProfileImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
URL url = null;

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileImages.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading images...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Gets all the notices from URL that correspond to the current user
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

        // Gets JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_profile_images, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("Profile images: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // Image found
                // Gets Array of notices
                images = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGES);

                // Loops through all images
                for (int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject image = images.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each JSON item in variable
                    imagePath = ("http://gatoandroidapp.comeze.com/" + image.getString(TAG_PATH));

                    //Gets image path and passed the image in bitmap format
                        try {
                            url = new URL(imagePath);
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                        }catch (IOException e) {

                        } 

                    // Creates new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // Ads child nodes to HashMap
                    map.put(TAG_PATH, bmp);

                    // Ads HashList to ArrayList
                    imagesList.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 */
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    //Dismiss the dialog after getting images
    pDialog.dismiss();

    //Updates UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

             //Updates parsed JSON data into ListView
             ListAdapter adapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(
                    ProfileImages.this, imagesList,
                    R.layout.profile_images_custom_gridview, new String[] {TAG_PATH},
                    new int[] {R.id.profilesImages_customGridView});

            //Updates ListView
           gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Code to pass the image url:

```
  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Creates intent
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), PictureView.class);

                //Sends image path to next view
                i.putExtra(TAG_PATH,  imagePath);

                startActivityForResult(i, 0);

            }
        });
```

Code that receive intent with image url (path)

```
 // Get image path from intent
      imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_PATH);

        //Load image from server into ImageView 
        profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView_imageView);
        URL url = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imagePath);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }catch (IOException e) {

        }
       profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you logging the path sent in the intent?

Comment: how are you getting imagePath in this line ? //Sends image path to next view
                i.putExtra(TAG_PATH,  imagePath);

Comment: set the image url to the View using view.settag() and get it in onItemClick method..post the getView() method of the Adapter..

Comment: Hi, I'm sending this image pass  imagePath = ("http://gatoandroidapp.comeze.com/" + image.getString(TAG_PATH));, i should probably sent the bitmap image instead of that path, the path i'm passing must be the path of the last image received from the server, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have declared `imagePath` with Class-level scope. Since at the end of for loop `imagePath` is updated with the last item URL so you're always passing the url of the last image.

To resolve the issue, make use of `View.setTag()` and  `View.getTag()` methods to pass the URL (or) Use the `position` in `onItemClick()` to retrieve the 
`JSONObject image = images.getJSONObject(position);` and construct the URL.

Comment: Hi, I've been doing that for a while now, I already passed the url using setTag() now i'm trying to get the tag when the item is clicked but I'm having some trouble, first time using setTag and getTag